# Get the value of an XML element in a file folder

Tags: java, xml

Im working on a program which read xml file in a folder and then get the `<name> MyName </name>` which inside the xml file btw this is my xml file looks like

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -<Config> <Name>MyName</Name> ..... </Config>
```

I want to get the value of the `<name>` this is what i have for now

```
File directory = new File(txtSource.getText());
            File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
            for (File file : fList) {
                if (file.getName().startsWith("Config")) {
                    try {
                        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                        Document document = builder.parse(new File(file.toString()));
                        Element rootElement = document.getDocumentElement();
                        rootElement.getAttribute("name");
                        System.out.println(rootElement);
                    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

I tried my code and this is the output which is wrong

```
[Config: null]
```

Comment: suppose this [example](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) is have a solution and has a better approach to your problem.

Comment: Yoow @RajithPemabandu thanks i didn't see that link on google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
    File directory = new File(txtSource.getText());
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    for (File file : fList) {
        if (file.getName().startsWith("Config")) {
            try {
                DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document document = builder.parse(file);
                Element rootElement = document.getDocumentElement();
                NodeList nameTags = rootElement.getElementsByTagName("Name");
                Node nameTag = nameTags.item(0);
                System.out.println("tag name: " + nameTag.getNodeName());
                System.out.println("tag text: " + nameTag.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
```